# Why Jquery plugin duplicates do NOT work

Tags: php, html, jquery-plugins

I recently downloaded a JQuery rotating banner plugin from: http://www.mclelun.com/labs/#jqbanner. 
I noticed that When I have one rotating banner on my page it works brilliantly, however when I try to add another one, only one of them, the first rotating banner will work. The second one will not work.

How do I get both rotating banners to work simultaneously?

Below is my code:

```
//##########################################
//###### The first Banner rotator ##########
//##########################################

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqbanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqbanner.css" />
```

Include the list of banners
To tell the script which images in your page are for rotating banners.

```
<div id="jqb_object">

<div class="jqb_slides">
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner1.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner2.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title"><a href="slide link"><img src="banner3.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><span>TEXT SLIDE IN DIV</span></div></div>

<div class="jqb_bar">
<div class="jqb_info"></div>
<div id="btn_next" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_next"></div>
<div id="btn_pauseplay" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_pause"></div>
<div id="btn_prev" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_prev"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

The above will work. However when I try to add a new banner like the code below:

```
//##########################################
//###### The second Banner rotator #########
//##########################################

<div id="jqb_object">

<div class="jqb_slides">
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner1.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><a href="slide link"><img src="banner2.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title"><a href="slide link"><img src="banner3.jpg"/></a></div>
<div class="jqb_slide" title="slide title" ><span>TEXT SLIDE IN DIV</span></div></div>

<div class="jqb_bar">
<div class="jqb_info"></div>
<div id="btn_next" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_next"></div>
<div id="btn_pauseplay" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_pause"></div>
<div id="btn_prev" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_prev"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

The second banner rotator will not work

looking forward to your reply.

Sir BT

Answer (score 1):

That's because the plugin works with IDs, e.g., `id="jqb_object"`, and those are defined to be unique on a page. Browsers take usually the first one, if an author doubles an ID by accident.

In your case, you can either hack the plugin (search for '#' and replace with '.'), but chances are, that this is more complicated to fix, contact the author and tell the problem or search for another plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am going to try hacking it cause I cant seem to find a better plugin.

Comment: You will need to pay attention to global variables (and those "global" in the scope of the plugin). You can circumvent those with something like [$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: I dont get it, it seems easy but... could you demonstrate how you would have done it on this piece of code:

Comment: I dont get it, it seems easy but... could you demonstrate how you would have done it on this piece of code: